# What dialectal language can I expect in Jeju-do?

Tags: dialects

I will be traveling to Jeju-do soon.
How much Jeju dialect can I expect to hear (or overhear)?
And what are the most common phrases or words that I might hear or see?

Comment: Jeju dialect is almost gone and nobody uses it unless among Jeju people themselves. You will never hear it unless you specifically ask Jeju people to speak it.

Comment: @Rathony I think OP is asking how much Jeju dialect is spoken among Jeju natives, rather than how much the natives will use it to talk to OP.

Comment: @busukxuan "Jeju dialect is almost gone and nobody uses it"  is to "How much can I expect to hear?".  "unless among Jeju people themselves" is to "How much can I expect to **over**hear? :-)

Comment: My one friend from Jeju was very hard to understand in both Korean and English. I don't know if his accent was typical or his personal idiosyncracy.

Answer (score 3):

The phrase you might be most likely to hear is **혼저 옵서예**, which is the 제주 equivalent of '어서 오세요'.

[image]